# Using String as array and use it in a query

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP file and getting via POST this string:

```
$temas = $_POST['temas']; //$temas = ".45.12.34"
```

Where each of the numbers should be the id for a table record.

And I have following query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_preguntas WHERE tema = '".$temas."'";
```

I need to put in the WHERE part of the query each of the received id

Something like that: ... WHERE tema = 45 OR tema = 12 OR tema = 34

Of course, on each execution the string changes.

I have tried using the PHP explode function, but I don't know how to implement the result in the query.

Comment: replace dot(.) by comma(,) and use mysql where IN()

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, you mean first remove the dot(.), then replace (.) with (,) and finally use WHERE IN($temas) . ?

Comment: yes, or you can directly use explode by dot(.) and use it in where IN()

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and probably should look to resolve :)

Comment: @mvasco I could write up an answer explaining that you should first sanitise your input a bit `trim($temas, '.');` to remove any unnecessary periods, then you could do `str_replace('.', ',', $temas);` to get it into the correct format for an SQL IN.... But i think really that's a really shitty answer for you :), this looks like an xy problem http://xyproblem.info/. The way you're trying to do it is a bit shonky/dangerous, so a better answer for you would require more details, such as why is your POST format looking like ".45.12.34", can we improve that?

Comment: @MLeFevre, no, the POST format is not my job, it is as it is

Comment: @mvasco sad but it happens! What's the next step in your code? What are you feeding your `$query` to?

Comment: @MLeFevre, please publish your answer if you want

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, may be you can answer my question in a safer way, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer won't differ too much from everyone else's but it is an answer to address SQL injection + a solution

```
$temas = implode(',', explode('.', $_POST['temas']));
$temas = trim($temas);

$res = $conn->prepare('select * from `tb_preguntas` WHERE `tema` in (:temas)');
$res->execute(array(':temas' => $temas));
```

here we use a prepared statement, now you're code is safe woop woop

Comment: Much better to address the SQL injection issue as well rather than just ignoring it for the sake of internet points

Answer (score 1):

best case scenario

```
$temas = implode(',', explode( '.', $_POST['temas']));
$query = "select * from tb_preguntas WHERE tema in (" . $temas . ")";
```

but your case, . comes first that makes life so much harder, so a better solution would be

```
$temas1 = explode( '.', $_POST['temas'] );
$temas2 = array();
foreach( $temas1 as $value ) {
   if( is_numeric( $value )) $temas2[] = $value;
}
$query = "select * from tb_preguntas WHERE tema in (" . implode( ',' , $temas2 ) . ")";
```

Comment: you probably have to first trim the first dot in the $temas variable...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above you can use the IN() function of mysql, however you have to remove the first period '.' and change the rest to commas ','.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_preguntas` WHERE `tema` IN('".str_replace('.',',',trim($temas,'.'))."') ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` to split those numbers by `.`And it must turn into array.

Then run your queries into a loop using the lenth of the array like this:

```
$id = explode('.',$temas);
    foreach($id as $temas_id) {    
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_preguntas WHERE tema = '".$temas_id."'";
      if(isset($conn->query(query ))) {
        // Execute code here if there's a result.
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
$temas = $_POST['temas']; 

$temas = explode('.',$temas);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_stipe WHERE tema in '".implode("', '", $temas)."'");
```

This code is working fine.